# Arithmetic series in Ruby

Tags: ruby, series

I am trying to write a function in ruby that returns "Arithmetic" when the input is an arithmetic series array(the delta between a number and the consecutive number in the array is the same across the array). Here's what I have for so far:

```
array = [1,3,5,7,9] #arithmetic series input example  
array.each_cons(2).map {|x,y| y - x == array[2] - array[1]}
```

This returns the following

```
[true,true,true,true,true]
```

My goal is to write a function that identifies what kind of series the array is, if there is one at all. Here's what I am trying to build

```
def isarithemetic(array)
if array.each_cons(2).map {|x,y| y - x == array[2] - array[1]} == true
    return "arithmetic"
```

I am open to new suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an array `arr` contains integer values, those (ordered) values comprise at most one arithmetic expression.  If the average interval is integer-valued (i.e.,

```
  ((arr.last-arr.first) % (arr.size-1).zero?
```

is true), a unique progression is given by the values of `arr.first`, `arr.last` and `arr.size`, namely:

```
  avg_interval = (arr.last-arr.first)/(arr.size-1)
  (arr.first..arr.last).step(avg_interval).to_a
```

If the average interval is not integer-valued, it cannot be an arithmetic progression, but we don't need to check that condition.  That's because by using integer arithmetic to compute `avg_interval`, the resulting arithmetic progression cannot equal `arr` if the average interval is not integer-valued.

Hence, rather than check if all the intervals are equal, we could just check to see if the above arithmetic progression equals `arr`.

**Code**

```
def arithmetic_progression?(arr)
  return true if arr.size < 2
  (arr.first..arr.last).step((arr.last-arr.first)/(arr.size-1)).to_a == arr
end
```

**Examples**

```
arithmetic_progression?([1,3,5,7,9]) #=> true
arithmetic_progression?([1,3,5,7,8]) #=> false
```

In the first example:

```
arr = [1,3,5,7,9]
avg_interval = (arr.last-arr.first)/(arr.size-1) #=> 2
(arr.first..arr.last).step(avg_interval).to_a    #=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

In the second:

```
arr = [1,3,5,7,8]
avg_interval = (arr.last-arr.first)/(arr.size-1) #=> 1
(arr.first..arr.last).step(avg_interval).to_a    #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You could then write, for example:

```
arithmetic_progression?([1,3,5,7,9]) ? "Arithmetic progression" :
  "Not arithmetic progression" #=> "Arithmetic progression"
```

**Variant**

The method could probably be made slightly more efficient by inserting the following line after the first line of the method:

```
return false unless ((arr.last-arr.first) % (arr.size-1)).zero?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using `all?`:

```
array.each_cons(2).map {|x,y| y - x == array[2] - array[1]}.all?
```

or perhaps

```
array.each_cons(2).all? {|x,y| y - x == array[2] - array[1]}
```

Comment: What exactly is going on there with `array.each_cons(2).all?`. The fact that it doesn't have `each` or `map` makes me uncomfortable. hahah